# Calculate Unique cells with similar data Count Between Columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel which has 6 columns. First Column has a unique reference for each row. Row B has Names of staff and Column C to F has the status of the work and reasons why it was not completed. I want a function to calculate the total of uncompleted task for each staff. So either Column C or D or E or F says "No" I want to count it as 1 for that staff. So if Row 5 6 and 7 is assigned to Jane and  Different columns for her has a "No" I want the count to be only 3 and not to count every column that has a No. How can i do this?

Comment: This question could be understood ***much*** better, if you provide a screenshot, containing 5 rows with examples and a manually filled column 8 explaining what you want to see there by the wanted formula.

Comment: How can I attach an excel here?

Comment: You may only upload it elsewhere and place the URL here. But I'd prefer a screenshot, if it explains everything, as can be read directly by every reader. If I explain my own answers with a picture, then I take a screenshot with the Windows Snipping Tool and paste it here via the image-icon above the text directly in the "paste here" box (it's also indirect via Imgur, but very easy to use).

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds like a `COUNTIF()` solution. Please check this:

[image: Example Screenshot with Formulas]

I also added a `SUMIF()` formula to get an overall addition of all numbers per staff.